# R language, nonlinear model formula predict

Tags: r, predict, nls

I fit an exponential formula with a set of data (x, y). then I want to calculate the y values from the formula with x values beyond the actual data set. It does't work, always prints the y values for the actual x values. Here is the code. What have I done wrong? What's the solution for my task with R language:

```
data <- data.frame(x=seq(1,69), y=othertable[1:69, 2])
nlsxypw <- nls(data$y ~ a*data$x^b, col2_60, start=list(a=2200000, b=0))
predict(nlsxypw)
#here I want to calculate the y values for x = 70-80
xnew <- seq(70, 80, 1)
predict(nlsxypw, xnew)

#it doesn't print these values, still the actual values for x=1~69.
```

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a strange feature with `predict.nls` (possibly other `predict` methods as well?), but you have to supply the new data with the same name that your model was defined in terms of:

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:69, 
  y = ((1:69)**2)+rnorm(69,0,5))
nlsxypw <- nls(y ~ a*(x^b),
               data=Data,
               start=list(a=2.5, b=1))
##
xnew <- 70:80
## note how newdata is specified
y.pred <- predict(nlsxypw, newdata=list(x=xnew))
> y.pred
 [1] 4900.355 5041.359 5184.364 5329.368 5476.373 5625.377 5776.381 5929.386 6084.390 6241.393 6400.397
##
with(
  Data,
  plot(x,y,pch=20,
       xlim=c(0,90),
       ylim=c(0,6700)))

lines(fitted(nlsxypw),col="red")
points(
  x=xnew,
  y=y.pred,
  pch=20,
  col="blue")
##
```

[image]

Comment: It's not just `predict.nls`, it's pretty much every `predict()` function out there. Most expect a data.frame (or a list()) and the names of the variables must match exactly. That's why it's always a good idea to use the `data=` parameter as nrussell has done rather than using the "$" within your formula. There's no "special case" for when a model has just one independent co-variate.